# Adding Raster to Table of Content in ArcPy without losing information on General tab on layer properties?

Tags: arcpy, raster, data-management

I use the following python script to generate the layer file (.lyr) from raster in Geodatabase

```
import arcpy    

raster = "Raster path in gdb"
LYRpath = "C:...\layername.lyr"

arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(raster, "RasterName")
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management("Rastername", LYRpath, "RELATIVE", "10")
```

However, the layer file is missing information on the General tab (Description and Credit) on Layer Property. Am I missing a step here?

Answer (score 1):

You are making a layer file from the source data, i.e. the data in the geodatabase. The description and credits are properties *of the layer object in the map document*. Such information would not exist in the source data unless it has been written into the metadata of the dataset.

If you want your layer file to include that information as well as the symbology then you need to be accessing that object and not the actual data.

Below is a sample of code to achieve this:

```py
import arcpy

mxdpath = r"C:\Scratch\esriuksample\Untitled.mxd"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdpath) # Get map document object
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Layers")[0] # Get DataFrame
layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"",df)[1] # Get second layer
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(layer,"c:\scratch\esriuksample\wombat.lyr","RELATIVE","10")
print("Done!")
```